# getting error in oracle forms 10G but working in SQL developer

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, oracleforms

Dear All I am writing a code which is working fine in sqlplus or toad but not working in oracle forms can please anyone give me hint where i am doing worng

```
    INSERT INTO PROD_CUT_ISSU_MST (TRANS_ID, LOC_ID, DATED, FORM_DEPT_CODE, TO_DEPT_CODE,
                                    FINAL_IND, ISS_NUM, BUNDLE_QTY, COMP_CODE,ACTUAL_DATE)
           VALUES ((select MAX(T.TRANS_ID)+1  from prod_cut_issu_mst t ), 2, TRUNC(SYSDATE),
                                    13, 14, 'N',(prod_validations.get_autobar('PCI', 1,2 )),5,1, TRUNC(SYSDATE));
```

it throws this error in oracle forms but works fine plsql or toad

**encountered the symbol "select" when expecting one of the following: (-+case...**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rewrite it to

```
INSERT INTO prod_cut_issu_mst (trans_id,
                               loc_id,
                               dated,
                               form_dept_code, --> is this really "form"? Not "from"?
                               to_dept_code,
                               final_ind,
                               iss_num,
                               bundle_qty,
                               comp_code,
                               actual_date)
   SELECT MAX (t.trans_id) + 1 trans_id,
          2  loc_id,
          TRUNC (SYSDATE) dated,
          13 form_dept_code,
          14 to_dept_code,
          'N' final_ind,
          prod_validations.get_autobar ('PCI', 1, 2) iss_num,
          5  bundle_qty,
          1  comp_code,
          TRUNC (SYSDATE) actual_date
     FROM prod_cut_issu_mst t;
```

Though, note that what you're doing is most probably **wrong** and it'll fail sooner or later in a multi-user environment, when two (or more) users select thte same `t.trans_id` and add `1` to it. If `trans_id` is supposed to be unique (such as a primary key column), `insert` will fail for all users but one (the one that commits first).

Comment: thanks @Littlefoot its worked, yes its just for single user so there is no need of sequence no multi users are working on this form  best regards.

Comment: @Zedan said _"yes its just for single user "_.     Well, for today anyway .....  ;-)   You should always design with possible future expansion in mind.  I once worked for an new auto assembly plant that had baked into all of their procedures and software the assumption that they would never build more than one model of vehicle, and never work but one shift per day.  That assumption lasted less than two years, and 15 years later, there was still code that was 'jumping through hoops' to deal with multiple models and 3 shifts.

Comment: "You should always design with possible future expansion in mind" - yes this is frequently done @EdStevens, *my experience* is, you *start* with a blown up code with lot of unnecessary features mostly prohibiting *preformace* and when this *expansion* appear you realize that you must redesign everything because the assumption years back were wrong. Here if *one process* populates the database the solution with `MAX` is preferable to the usage of a sequence even if you suspect in some years you will need a parallel load. IMO - stay calm and only after it is so far think a new solution.

Comment: @Littlefoot dear everything is working properly except this package line `prod_validations.get_autobar ('PCI', 1, 2) iss_num,` don't know why working properly when run in toad please if you have any idea??\

Comment: @Littlefoot ok i resolved by max value assigned to a variable everything is working fine regards